# Протестировать data класс

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, kotlin

Как возможно протестировать данный класс?

```
data class BreakdownEntry(val category: Category, val childList: List<BreakdownEntry>, val amount: Double,
                      val currencyCode: String, var percent: String = "")
```

Если б он к примеру использовался как `Serializable` то тогда б я б брал за основу данный класс и сэтил туда какие то данные для переменных, после чего проверял бы если данные которые я записал верны.

здесь же при попытке создать объект мне же походу надо и все эти параметры сразу в объект записывать, брр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы можете проверить что поля объектов не совпадают, каждый раз созадавая с разными параметрами:

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun testModelClass() {
    val category1 = Category().setGuid("category1").save()
    val category2 = Category().setGuid("category2").save()
    val breakdownEntry1 = BreakdownEntry(category1, emptyList(), 0.0, "", "")
    val breakdownEntry2 = BreakdownEntry(category2, emptyList(), 0.0, "", "")

    assertFalse(breakdownEntry1 == breakdownEntry2)
    assertFalse(breakdownEntry1.hashCode() == breakdownEntry2.hashCode())
}
```

Также при желании можно просто сэтить в параметры `percent` параметр какое то значение, после чего сравнивать его с начальным объектом.